# Fallback on Local js file If file is missing from remote path

Tags: jquery

i know how to load jquery file if CDN not accessible

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js">\x3C/script>'</script>
```

i was using a custom jquery plugin called `jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js`

and i was loading it from http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js this url but this url is not accessible now. i have this file in my local project folder. so just guide me how can i load this file if file can not be loaded from http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files url ? thanks

Comment: After including the lib from remote just check for any functions that the library expose. If the function doesn't exist, then load from local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
<script src="http://tab-slide-out.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    if(!jQuery().tabSlideOut) document.write('<script src="js/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>');
</script>
```